# Selective Form Text Color Change

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, razor

I want to change the color of the ' * ' to red within the form code below so they stand out more. So far I have not found a simple way to do this. ,  and custom tags don't work within forms.

```
<form name="requestForm" action="requestSent.cshtml" onsubmit="return validateRequest()" method="post">

<label>Email Address: *</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="customerEmail" /><br><br>

<label>First Name: *</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br>
<label>Last Name: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br><br>

<label>Phone Number: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" /><br><br>

<label>Request: *</label><br>
    <textarea name="customerRequest" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

<br>
* Required Fields
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a span to all of your `*`s.

```
<label>Email Address: <span class="red">*</span></label><br>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .red{
  color: red;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put * into the span tag and apply css to it like

html

```
<label>Email Address: <span class="redSpan">*</span></label>
```

css

```
.redSpan { color:#F00;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the * in a `span` and then apply a css rule for it

e.g.

```
.someclass {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<style type="text/css">
.required{color:red;}
</style>
<form name="requestForm" action="requestSent.cshtml" onsubmit="return validateRequest()" method="post">

<label>Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="customerEmail" /><br><br>

<label>First Name: <span class="required">*</span></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br>
<label>Last Name: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br><br>

<label>Phone Number: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" /><br><br>

<label>Request: <span class="required">*</span></label><br>
    <textarea name="customerRequest" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

<br>
<span class="required">*</span> Required Fields
```